# Eclipse Helios x64 (Mac) - JSP editor hangs/freezes

Tags: eclipse, jsp, osx-snow-leopard, 64-bit, freeze

I'm having issues with Eclipse Helios (3.6.2) x64 (32-bit, too) hanging/freezing frequently when I attempt to edit .jsp files using Eclipse's built-in editor (Web Tools, J2EE package). I've been doing editing with 3rd party apps, but I would really like to have proper JSP syntax highlighting and auto-completion. The same symptoms occur when I attempt to edit .html files in Eclipse, too (though it's not as much of an issue since little is lost using a 3rd party html editor).

They are just plain .jsp files... not part of a J2EE or Web Project. The issue seems to be whenever I attempt to add tags... but it doesn't seem to consistently cause the problem. It seems to be temperamental.

Think it's a reference issue of sorts? Auto-completion issue in Eclipse?

I saw that other people had issues with this, but I wasn't able to find a clear cut solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you know which version of WTP is in there?  Have you applied any updates that are available from the Helios Update Site?  How exactly are you going about adding tags?

Comment: @nitind Java EE Developer tools -> version 3.2.3.v201011031800-7b7GHfIFSK2WBRT6E1mcyFXGPnSh. I just recently downloaded the WTP... running the latest version of Helios that I'm aware of. I'm adding tags just by simply typing (auto-complete may be in play).

Comment: Still seems to happen with Indigo and Snow Leopard and not only with JSP files.

Comment: Check the eclipse error log. You might find some hints there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old question that probably is resolved already. But in case anyone comes across this question in a search, it might be helpful to know that there is a [bug reported about this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=317830)

Answer (score 0):

That usually happens as eclipse plug-ins are lazy loaded. JSP editor is loaded the first tim you attempt to load any JSP. It generally takes a while, ranging from few seconds to couple of minutes. Just wait for this duration the first time and the JSP editor would load very quickly until the next restart. My tip is to avoid closing/restarting eclipse altogether.

Also, to further speed up the load time, turn off any validators (such as JavaScript syntax validator) which you think you may never need.